# Calculate distribution limits of independent random variables with standard normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, normal-distribution

I want to calculate distribution limits:
$$\sqrt{n}\frac{\xi_1+\xi_2+\dots+\xi_n}{\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2+\dots+\xi_n^2} \xrightarrow {d} \text{? and } \frac{\xi_1+\xi_2+\dots+\xi_n}{\sqrt{\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2+\dots+\xi_n^2}} \xrightarrow {d} \text{?}$$
where $\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots,\xi_n,\dots$ are independent random variables with standard normal distribution. May somebody can help me? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let's denote

$$S_1 = \frac{\xi_1+\xi_2+...+\xi_n}{n}$$
$$S_1 = \frac{\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2 +...+\xi_n^2}{n}$$
According to the [CLT Multivariate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT)
$$
\sqrt{n} \left( 
\begin{pmatrix} S_1 \\\ S_2 \end{pmatrix} 
- \beta 
 \right)\xrightarrow{n \to +\infty}\mathcal{N}\left( 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} ,\Sigma \right)
$$
with
$$\beta =\begin{pmatrix} E(\xi) \\\ E(\xi^2) \end{pmatrix} $$
$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} V(\xi) & Cov(\xi,\xi^2) \\\ Cov(\xi,\xi^2) &V(\xi^2)  \end{pmatrix}$$
( $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ can be easily calculate)

Applying the [multivariate Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method)
$$\sqrt{n}\left(h\begin{pmatrix} S_1 \\\ S_2 \end{pmatrix} - h(\beta )\right) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty}\mathcal{N}\left( 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} ,(\nabla h(\beta))^T\Sigma (\nabla h(\beta))\right)$$

- For the first function: use $h(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$
- For the first function: use $h(x,y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}$

You will find the asymptotic distribution of your two functions $\frac{S_1}{S_2}$ and $\frac{S_1}{\sqrt{S_2}}$.